# Delphi Grid: How to get selectedrows count "on the fly"

Tags: delphi, datagrid, vcl

Using `SelectedRows.Count` I can get a count of the number of grid rows selected. For example, if the user selected 3 rows, I can put a button on the form and clicking that can show me the number selected. Fine.

BUT how could I update the number of rows as the user selects them ("on the fly"). I have tried many of the `Grid` events, like `OnColEnter` or `OnMouseDown`. They seem to update the count only when the user clicks just outside the data columns, and not when a row is first selected.

Not seeing events related to changing ROWS in the `Grid` component, I tried many events in the underlying data query, but they too were inconsistent or often required clicking in certain places. The best result I found (actual code) was after scrolling the query:

```
procedure TDataHerd10.QuCowsAfterScroll(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  if MenuOpt = 'UpdtInd' then MainView.NumSelEdit.Text:=
    IntToStr(MainView.CowSelGrid.SelectedRows.Count);
end;
```

This event seems to lag one behind, and adds one more to the count initially when the user abandons the multiselect to go back to a single row.

Seems like with the right event, I should be able to count the selected rows to report to the user as they select/unselect rows?

Comment: Did you try the `OnClick()` event? That's usually the normal event for most controls. In some controls, it's also triggered in cases which aren't actually a click, such as a combo box scrolling with up/down keyboard keys. Also, I think you should change the title of your question to either `Data Grid` or `TDBGrid`, because I got most of the way through your question thinking it was a `TStringGrid` you were talking about, and then had to re-read it as a `TDBGrid` instead.

Comment: Also, you might be better off using checkboxes. I can't remember the last application I've used where I had to hold control or shift to multi-select. Other than ancient code I got once which I actually re-wrote to use checkboxes.

Comment: @Jerry: Um... Windows Explorer? Outlook? Excel? You can't remember using any of them (all of which are applications that require Ctrl or Shift to multi-select)? There are millions of corporate users of Windows 7 that would disagree with what you wrote.

Comment: @Ken Okay well actually Explorer is so second nature for me that did slip past. Outlook, I rarely ever do so, it doesn't necessarily require me to do so. And Excel is a whole different story, that's not a straight-forward list. Either way, Explorer and Outlook both have options to use checkboxes instead, and sometimes when you install Windows on touch-screen devices, it enables checkboxes by default.

Comment: @Jerry: *I can't remember the last application*. Just checked. Explorer, Outlook and Excel are all *applications*, and *sometimes* not all Windows installations are on touch-screen devices. The majority of the planet are not using touch screen devices to run Windows (which includesmost of  the 12K plus devices on my network). My entire office just upgraded to Office 2016, and there's not a checkbox in sight in my Outlook email folder (and my inbox is absolutely a list). Avoid blanket statements you can't support. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** I found it trickier than I was expecting to modify my original
answer to reliably meet your requirement to have the select count displayed
when the form first shows.

Below are the essentials of the testbed project which I hope reliably behaves
as you asked for.  In addition to the DBGrid, the form has a TEdit, which I use
to ensure that the dbgrid is not initially focused (so as to make it easier to observe the dbgrid's behaviour) and 3 TButtons whose
functions should be self-evident from their OnClick handlers.

You'll notice that the code that catches the changing count of the
dbgrid's selection count is only triggered in the dbgrid's OnDrawColumnCell
event.  However, this is called rather too frequently (in my case over 700
times before the form is first displayed) to be doing something else
in the gui every time it is triggered.  So instead, the form has a variable
which keeps track of the selection count and only updates the display of it
when the count changes (in the SetSelectedCount setter).

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    [...]
  private
    FSelectedCount: Integer;
    procedure SetSelectedCount(const Value: Integer);
  public
    procedure ShowSelectedCount;
    property SelectedCount : Integer read FSelectedCount write SetSelectedCount;
  end;
 [...]

procedure TForm1.btnClearSelectedClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DBGrid1.SelectedRows.Clear;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnGetSelectedClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowSelectedCount;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnSetSelectedClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DBGrid1.SelectedRows.CurrentRowSelected := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;
    DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
  SelectedCount := DBGrid1.SelectedRows.Count;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ActiveControl := Edit1;  // so the grid does not have focus when the form is first shown
  SelectedCount := -1;
end;

procedure TForm1.SetSelectedCount(const Value: Integer);
begin
  if FSelectedCount <> Value then begin
    FSelectedCount := Value;
    ShowSelectedCount;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ShowSelectedCount;
begin
  Caption := IntToStr(DBGrid1.SelectedRows.Count);
end;
```

Original answer follows

I usually use `DataSet.AfterScroll` for doing non-gui things which need to be synchronised with its current row.  Unfortunately, it doesn't work so well with a DBGrid, as you've obviously found, not least because the current row's selection state in the grid can be changed (e.g. by clicking it) without the dataset scrolling.

Unfortunately,

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1CellClick(Column: TColumn);
begin
  Caption := IntToStr(DBGrid1.SelectedRows.Count);
end;
```

doesn't quite do the job, either, for the fairly obvious reason that you can extend a selection from the current row without using the mouse - e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> will do it, too.

However, if you just add

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1KeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift:
    TShiftState);
begin
  Caption := IntToStr(DBGrid1.SelectedRows.Count);
end;
```

that takes use of the keyboard to change the selection(s) into account and has so far resisted my attempts to wrong-foot it.  If you are allowing the user to do in-place editing in the grid, you might want to filter the `Key` values which are used to update your display of the selection count.

Btw, taking the keyboard wrinkleas well as the problem with AfterScroll into account, your q doesn't seem to deserve (to me at any rate) the downvote it's got , so I've given it a +1.

Comment: Perfect, with DBGrid1KeyUp! I might also add that the comment from @Jerry Doidge on creating a checkbox column of my own is a good idea in order to make it a bit more user friendly and be more "in style" when I get to a non-windows platform (later).

Comment: Actually, @ScottStalheim, I'm just about to post an update to my answer that shows an alternative method, that I prefer because it only requires a single call-site.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the detailed help, @Martyn. I got it working well now.  Your placement of a button for "ShowSelectedCount" was something i was already doing for testing purposes, but to be clear, the requirement to post the number selected "on the fly" means not having to click on a button in order to see the count updated.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a little more to the excellent answer from @Martyn...

In order to update the displayed count automatically ("on the fly"), I found the suggestion to use `Grid1.KeyUp` to update the count very good, but also added the count update on a couple other events. Most critical was `Grid1.MouseUp`. Without that, the user could click on a new row, outside the currently selected rows and lose all the row selections, BUT the displayed count would remain rather than go back to zero.